# How to escape 'T' in django's date template tag

Tags: python, django

I want to use `DATETIME_FORMAT = 'Y-n-jTH:i:s'` to display `2014-4-26T16:19:43`, But the result is `2014-4-26CST16:19:43`, How to Escape `T`(which is for timezone)? [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

Comment: doesn't CST stand for Central Standard Time?

Answer (score 5):

`'Y-n-j\TH:i:s'` works. See `echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');` on this [reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 0):

Standard datetime formatting requires preformatted characters to be surrounded in quotes. Try this:

```
DATETIME_FORMAT = "Y-n-j'T'H:i:s"
```

Comment: You get `2014-4-26'CST'16:19:43`. But I found out `Y-n-j\TH:i:s'` works.

Comment: Good to know! You should answer the question, no shame in writing the correct answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use the `c` value on its own, which matches the standard ISO format - which is what your desired format is.

Comment: no, `2008-01-02T10:30:00.000123+02:00` is not what I desired.